# Sequelize multi-tenancy - Loading models for multi databases

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js, multi-tenant

I am using sequelize providing access for multiple databases, based on subsite.
Example:
site1.mysite.com -> DB: site1
site2.mysite.com -> DB: site2

When I start my service, I load models pointing for each database, so based on each subsite I can use it to access my models.
My issue is how to escalate this, because I want to load my list of databases from another "master" DB, however the way I load the models on a sync way when loading the app, do not allow me to asynchronous load the list of databases. Any suggestions on how to load schemas only when needed, or to create a index.js file for loading models getting information from a external call?